# Is it possible to prevent a specific JavaScript error from being written to the console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, console.log, web-console

*Hypothetically* - let's say I have some JavaScript to handle the clicks of three different buttons:

```
$("#working").click(function () {
    alert("Seth Rollins is the greatest champion of all time.");
    console.log("WWE World Heavyweight Champion");
});

$("#fix-this-error").click(function () {
    alert(this_should_not_show_up_in_the_console);
    console.log("This won't show");
});

$("#should-error").click(function () {
    alert(oipewavqn2389tvb3t8ahwleuhtvab3iwuthabvlewiuweaqhaoiuhva98r3b2);
    console.log("This won't show either");
});
```

The **first** one will work as it alerts a string, and it will log to the console the message that is written after the alert.

The **second** and **third** functions will not work because they are trying to alert variables that are not defined. Their subsequent `console.logs` will not output anything.

**My Question:** Is it possible to prevent the error from the **second** function from outputting to the console while maintaining the following properties?:

- The **first** function should work as intended
- The **second** function's subsequent `console.log` still should *not* execute
- The **third** function (and any other functions) should still output their errors

**Edit:** Here is a fiddle to play around in - https://jsfiddle.net/5m40LLmm/2/

**SUPER EDIT:** I don't want the execution of logic in the **second** function to really change. I ***want*** the error to be thrown, and the `.click()` handler should exit before it reaches console.log as it does now. I just want to prevent the error from being shown. I don't want to use `try` and `catch` to circumvent the error or to somehow check if the variable exists before I use `alert()`. I know and *want* the error to happen, I just want to prevent its display. I hope that makes this more clear.

Comment: [try catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: Why don't you want to use try catch? It's exactly the feature you are looking for!

Comment: Wow I am looking at this question 2 years later and I have NO IDEA what the **** I was thinking. What could I have possibly been trying to do? It makes no sense to me and I am the one that wrote it. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run this, the console.log function is never actually called. The alert function fails, logs that it failed, and the click listener function exits. `console.log()` is never reached. This means you just need to stop the alert from showing an error. This is where [try catch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp) statements are helpful.

```
$("#fix-this-error").click(function () {
    try {
        alert(this_should_not_show_up_in_the_console);
        console.log("This won't show");
    } catch (e) {
        // Code jumps here when `alert()` fails.
        // `e` stores information about the error
        // If you don't want to put everything in the try/catch,
        // you can stop the function from continuing execution with
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: You are right in that alert fails and click exits. I want this functionality.(No logic should progress after the error) I just don't want the error to show. I'll update my question to be more clear as people seem confused

Comment: That's what this does

Comment: yeah but it doesn't break the click function. You see in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5m40LLmm/3/  that if I insert console.log() after the try/catch, it is still executed. I don't want anything else in the flick function executed after the error occurs. I am pretty sure what I am asking for is nearly impossible lol

Comment: Updated. Using the `return` keyword will stop the function.

Answer (score 4):

Use [try catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

```
$("#fix-this-error").click(function () {
    try {
        alert(this_should_not_show_up_in_the_console);
        console.log("This won't show");
    } catch() {}
});
```

or check to see if the [variable is defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) before you try to use it.

Comment: sorry, please refer to my "super edit" in the question. I don't want to prevent the error from happening, I just want to prevent it's display in the console

Comment: great, that is my question. If you have any knowledge that proves you can 100% not do this I would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `typeof` keyword to check if a particular variable is defined or not.

[typeof documentation](https://jsfiddle.net/5m40LLmm/2/)

```
$("#fix-this-error").click(function () {
    if (typeof this_should_not_show_up_in_the_console !== "undefined")
    {
        alert(this_should_not_show_up_in_the_console);
        console.log("This won't show");
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry, please refer to my "super edit" in the question. I don't want to prevent the error from happening, I just want to prevent it's display in the console